# react-native: where did info.plist go?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm a beginner react-native developer and now considering a third party component.

In order to use this component, it's necessary to modify a file called `info.plist`.
However, my project (made in React-native 0.49) doesn't have such a file.

As far as I know, this file is used in iOS native apps and used to exist in older versions of React-native (correct me if it's wrong).

So, the question is, how should we deal with third party components which need modifications on `info.plist`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you create your app? with `create-react-native-app` or expo or `react-native-init`?

Comment: I made it with `create-react-native-app`. I use `expo` for testing.

Comment: expo doesn't support native coding and settings. From [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native) _The most limiting thing about Expo is that you can’t add in your own native modules without detaching and using ExpoKit._